# Why does `.data` pronoun use variables from environment, not data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

Consider the following example code:

```r
library(dplyr)
colname = "bar"
d = tibble(foo = 1:5, bar = 2:6, colname = "foo")
filter(d, .data[[colname]] == 3)
```

There are *two* `colname` variables, one global and one defined in the tibble `d`. So which one should `filter()` use? Well, according to `?dplyr::filter` documentation, the second argument in the function call should be an expression

> that return a logical value, and are defined in terms of the variables in `.data`.

Here, `.data` is the name of the first argument to `filter()`. But in the expression used in the function call, I haved used the `.data` *pronoun* (which is not the same as the `.data` *argument*). And maybe this is looking for objects in a different place? Let’s check. The `?rlang::.data` documentation states that:

> `.data` retrieves data-variables from the data frame.

OK, so everywhere we look, the documentation is saying that things are being looked for in the data frame, not in the environment. In other words, it’s the `colname` variable in `d` (with value `foo`) that will be used. But when we run the command, we get:

```r
filter(d, .data[[colname]] == 3)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>     foo   bar colname
#>   <int> <int> <chr> 
#> 1     2     3 foo
```

So it’s actually the `colname` value from the environment (with value `bar`) that is used. Why?! Expected output would be:

```r
filter(d, foo == 3)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>     foo   bar colname
#>   <int> <int> <chr> 
#> 1     3     4 foo
```

Comment: You are addressing variable not string. Otherwise you need .data[["colname" ]] instead. In this case d$colname will be accessed. So everything is correct

Comment: @asd-tm OK, but which part of the documentation says that that’s the why the `.data` pronoun works when it receives a variable name? Especially in light of the fact that variable names in `filter()` in general refers to variables in the `.data` argument (if they exist), not in the evironment.

Comment: See here: ?\`[[\`. Quote: "Both '$' and '[[' can be applied to environments.  Only character indices are allowed... "

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at different expressions using the `.data` and `.env` pronouns. I slightly altered the example data, see below:

```r
library(dplyr)

colname = "bar"
d = tibble(foo = 1:6, bar = 2:7, colname = rep(c("bar", "foo"), 3))
```

As already mentioned in the comments by @asd-tm, the expression below is correct
`.data[[colname]]` equals `.data[["bar"]]`

```r
filter(d, .data[[colname]] == 3)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>     foo   bar colname
#>   <int> <int> <chr>  
#> 1     2     3 foo
```

If want to select the column `columname` we’d do this:
However, there are no rows corresponding to `colname == 3`

```r
filter(d, .data$colname == 3)
#> # A tibble: 0 × 3
#> # … with 3 variables: foo <int>, bar <int>, colname <chr>
```

The above is equivalent to:

```r
filter(d, colname == 3)
#> # A tibble: 0 × 3
#> # … with 3 variables: foo <int>, bar <int>, colname <chr>
```

Rows are selected when `colname` actually corresponds to the given value:

```r
filter(d, colname == "foo")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>     foo   bar colname
#>   <int> <int> <chr>  
#> 1     2     3 foo    
#> 2     4     5 foo    
#> 3     6     7 foo
```

If we want to use an object from the parent environment, we can use `.env`

```r
filter(d, colname == .env$colname)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>     foo   bar colname
#>   <int> <int> <chr>  
#> 1     1     2 bar    
#> 2     3     4 bar    
#> 3     5     6 bar
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>